# create a secondary y-axis in R

Tags: r, histogram, axis

I had a question regarding creating secondary y-axis in R. Here is an example dataset

```
#generate some artifical data

per_cur <- runif(1171, 0.1, 7.62)
obs<-runif(1171,100,1000)

#create a density histogram of per_cur 

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
op <- par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.5)
hist(per_cur, prob=TRUE, border="white",main=NULL,las=1,cex.axis=0.8,ann = FALSE)
lines(density(per_cur), col="blue",lwd=2)

#add obs with a secondary y-axis

par(new = TRUE)
plot(per_cur,obs, cex=.5, pch=16, col=adjustcolor("black",alpha=0.2), axes = FALSE, ylab="Density")
axis(4,cex.axis=0.5)
```

It produces a plot which tells me the distribution of `per_cur` and also shows my the relationship
between `per_cur` and `obs` through the secondary y-axis. However, when I run the following code with the only
difference that I set the limit of primary y-axis using `ylim=c(0,0.3)` you can see the plot completely changes.
It gives the impression that relationship between the `obs` and `pre_cur` is different in both plots (more `obs` points
    come under the curve in first plot compared to the second plot).

```
op <- par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.5)
hist(per_cur, prob=TRUE,ylim=c(0,0.3), border="white",main=NULL,las=1,cex.axis=0.8,ann = FALSE)
lines(density(per_cur), col="blue",lwd=2)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(per_cur,obs, cex=.5, pch=16, col=adjustcolor("black",alpha=0.2), axes = FALSE, ylab="Density")
axis(4,cex.axis=0.5)
```

I wanted to ask is there any way my secondary y-axis also get adjusted as I adjust the primary y-axis limit so that
equal number of `obs` points are under the curve in both plots. Hope this is clear. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by manipulating the ylim on each plot. For example:

```
#generate some artifical data

per_cur <- runif(1171, 0.1, 7.62)
obs<-runif(1171,100,1000)

#create a density histogram of per_cur 


# use these variables to set the limits on all plots
y1max = max(density(per_cur)$y)
y2max = max(obs)



par(mfrow=c(2,1))
op <- par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.5)
hist(per_cur, prob=TRUE, ylim = c(0, y1max), border="white",main=NULL,las=1,cex.axis=0.8,ann = FALSE)
lines(density(per_cur), col="blue",lwd=2)

#add obs with a secondary y-axis

par(new = TRUE)
plot(per_cur,obs, cex=.5, ylim = c(0, y2max), pch=16, col=adjustcolor("black",alpha=0.2), axes = FALSE, ylab="Density")
axis(4,cex.axis=0.5)
```

Then you scale each axis by the same factor:

```
# used to scale the axes
factor <- 2

op <- par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.5)
hist(per_cur, prob=TRUE, ylim = c(0, y1max * factor), border="white",main=NULL,las=1,cex.axis=0.8,ann = FALSE)
lines(density(per_cur), col="blue",lwd=2)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(per_cur,obs, cex=.5, ylim = c(0, y2max * factor),pch=16, col=adjustcolor("black",alpha=0.2), axes = FALSE, ylab="Density")
axis(4,cex.axis=0.5)
```

[image]